# Measure the time in which a request is sent to zuul proxy

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I have multiple microservices made in spring boot which communicates with a zuul proxy.My problem is that the requests are taking too much time and i would like to measure the time spent from when the request gets to the proxy and the time in which the request gets forwarded from the proxy to my microservices.Are there any ways to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other approach similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59267512/11733759) can be done with `ZuulFilter`.
Below code was written without checking it so there can be some errors but it should show the idea.
First add Pre filter

```java
public class PreFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PreFilter.class);

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return PRE_DECORATION_FILTER_ORDER - 1; // run before PreDecoration
    }

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return PRE_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();
        long startTime = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
        logger.info("Request URL::" + request.getRequestURL().toString() +
        ":: Start Time=" + Instant.now());
        ctx.put("startTime", startTime);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then in Post filter

```java
public class PostFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PostFilter.class);
    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return POST_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return SEND_RESPONSE_FILTER_ORDER - 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();
        long startTime = (Long) ctx.get("startTime");

        logger.info("Request URL::" + request.getRequestURL().toString() +
   ":: Time Taken=" + (Instant.now().toEpochMilli() - startTime));
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try what was written [here](https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring/log-incoming-requests-spring/) and add custom RequestInterceptor:

```java
@Component
public class CustomRequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

 private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomRequestInterceptor.class);

 @Override
 public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {

  long startTime = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
  logger.info("Request URL::" + request.getRequestURL().toString() +
   ":: Start Time=" + Instant.now());
  request.setAttribute("startTime", startTime);
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {

  long startTime = (Long) request.getAttribute("startTime");

  logger.info("Request URL::" + request.getRequestURL().toString() +
   ":: Time Taken=" + (Instant.now().toEpochMilli() - startTime));
 }
}
```

To get something like this in log:

```
2018-09-30 12:02:09.704  INFO 51707 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] com.example.CustomRequestInterceptor     : Request URL::http://localhost:8080/log-incoming-request:: Start Time=2018-09-30T06:32:08.861Z
2018-09-30 12:02:16.820  INFO 51707 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] com.example.CustomRequestInterceptor     : Request URL::http://localhost:8080/log-incoming-request:: Time Taken=9942
```

In configuration:

```java
@Configuration
public class RequestAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

 @Autowired
 private CustomRequestInterceptor customRequestInterceptor;

 @Override
 public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
  registry.addInterceptor(customRequestInterceptor)
   .addPathPatterns("/**/path_to_zull_request/**/");
 }
}
```

Comment: I've added that class but it doesn't log anything :(

Comment: Did you add it in Configuration? @TrSorin

Comment: I'm not sure about path to zuul request..do i have to put there the path of my microservice that is calling zuul?

Comment: I think that it should be path to zuul request @TrSorin

Comment: I have microservices which call zull proxy. Do i have to put there the zuul endpoint or the endpoints of my microservices?

Comment: i'm not sure if the path is right because it's not logging anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203987/discussion-between-lczapski-and-tr-sorin).